# Magento Index issue

Tags: magento, magento2

Error in `catalog_search`

When I run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` I get an error

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex 
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Inventory index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Search index process unknown error:
```

[image]

I was expecting a clear output without an error but somehow got stuck this error, due to which I can't see my product that I had added in my Magento website.